# SPARQL: Select attribute of all resource subject of category

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I have this SPARQL query to select all resources beloning to the Wikipedia category `National_parks_in_California`:

```
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>

SELECT * WHERE {
  ?park dcterms:subject dbc:National_parks_in_California .
}
```

which [returns](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20dcterms%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20*%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fpark%20dcterms%3Asubject%20dbc%3ANational_parks_in_California%20.%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

```
park
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Death_Valley_National_Park
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Yosemite_National_Park
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Channel_Islands_National_Park
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Kings_Canyon_National_Park
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Lassen_Volcanic_National_Park
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Redwood_National_and_State_Parks
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Joshua_Tree_National_Park
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Pinnacles_National_Park
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Sequoia_National_Park
```

Is it possible to build a query to return along with the dbpedia resource page also the `foaf:homepage` of each resource?

I wrote

```
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

SELECT * WHERE {
  ?park dcterms:subject dbc:National_parks_in_California .
  ?webpage foaf:homepage ?park .
}
```

but it [returns](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20dcterms%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20foaf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20*%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fpark%20dcterms%3Asubject%20dbc%3ANational_parks_in_California%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fwebpage%20foaf%3Ahomepage%20%3Fpark%20.%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on) zero results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you open on of the results, you will see that each resource MIGHT have a `foaf:homepage`. Therefore, the direction of your query is wrong

```
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
SELECT * WHERE {
      ?park dcterms:subject dbc:National_parks_in_California .
      optional{
            ?park foaf:homepage ?homepage.
      }
}
```

The reason I have used `optional` is that some resources do not have `foaf:homepage`.